# Django rules re-using predicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, web, django-rules

I've created 2 predicate's, which are extremely similar in nature. One consumes a list and the other a static string.

```
@rules.predicate
def can_edit_items(user, fields):
    for perm in user.groups.all()
        if perm.name not in settings.fields[fields]
            return False
    return True

@rules.predicate
def can_edit_specific_item(user, field):
    for perm in user.groups.all()
        if perm.name not in settings.fields[field]
            return False
    return True
```

My requirements are that `can_edit_specific_item()` must make use of `can_edit_items()` by passing in a single string `field_1`

I've tried creating the following variation but it doesn't seem to work as I intend it to

```
@rules.predicate
def can_edit_specific_item(user, field):
    for perm in user.groups.all()
        if perm.name not in can_edit_items[field]
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define `can_edit_specific_item` by setting @rules.predicate inside `can_edit_specific_item` and returning this as a func, having only passed in your required field.

I'm a little unsure of the wider requirements, but maybe this might do the trick

```
def can_edit_specific_item(*field):
    @rules.predicate
    def predicate(user):
        return can_edit_items(user, field)
    return predicate
```